# What ranks do the individual members of the Ghost crew hold in the Rebellion?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, the-rebel-alliance

I would like to know what ranks the members of the Ghost crew hold within the Rebellion at the time of Season 3. The members I am talking about are:

- Ezra Bridger
- Hera Syndulla
- Kanan Jarrus
- Sabine Wren
- Zeb Orellios
- "Chopper"
- "Rex"
- And AP-5, because why not?

Comment: Kanan is the biggest mystery. A former commander in the Grand Army of the Republic, and now a full Jedi Knight in season 3, he should hold a very senior position. But yet he seems to exist outside the rebellion hierarchy

Comment: I believe Hera is referred to as Captain by other members of the Rebellion such as Commander Sato. As a bonus,by the time of rogue one, Hera Syndulla is a General.

Comment: @DBPriGuy We know that someone with the last name 'Syndulla' is a general; it could be Hera, or it could be her father, Cham. Given Cham's experience leading resistance movements, he's probably more likely to be a general than Hera.

Comment: @Werrf: I thought so too, myself. But as an aside on another answer on this site, someone confirmed that the General Syndulla they referred to is indeed Hera and not Cham. Let's see if I can find it to link here

Comment: @Werrf: couldn't find good proof on-site but here it is, from Dave Filoni: http://ew.com/movies/rogue-one-rebels-references/rogue-one-and-rebels-6

Comment: I thought Cham bought it in one of the new canon books that goes before Rebels.

Comment: @Paul You're probably thinking of *Lords of the Sith*, where he does appear but is one of the few named Twi'leks *not* killed. He's since appeared in seasons 2 and 3 of *Rebels*, but we don't know for sure if he's alive by the time of *Rogue One*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Ezra - Lieutenant and/or Lieutenant Commander

Ezra is promoted early in the season 3 premiere "Steps into Shadow":

> **Commander Sato:** Ezra Bridger, I trusted you with the last mission, and your success has not gone unnoticed. You will lead this mission as Lieutenant Commander.
>
> **Ezra:** Lieutenant? A promotion?
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 3 Episode 1: "Steps into Shadow"</sup>

Ezra gets his command suspended as a result of his actions in this episode, but it's not clear what it does to his rank; in the episode "Twin Suns", he's referred to as "Lieutenant", which may or may not be a short form for the higher rank:

> **Rebel:** Hey, Lieutenant. What you got there?
>
> **Ezra:** Oh, some munitions for the A-wings. Where do you want 'em?
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 3 Episode 19: "Twin Suns"</sup>

However, in the season 3 finale, Ezra is referred to as a "Commander":

> **Sato:** Commander Bridger, go to heading 221 and prepare to jump.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 3 Episode 20: "Zero Hour: Part 1"</sup>

And in an early season 4 episode, Mon Mothma uses Ezra's full title, confirming that he is a Lieutenant Commander by this point.

### Hera - Captain, later General

According to the [trivia gallery](http://www.starwars.com/episodes/steps-into-shadow-trivia-gallery) for "Steps into Shadow" on StarWars.com, Hera is a full Captain in the Rebellion:

[image]

> Hera now has a traditional rebel rank badge on her sleeve indicating she is a captain.

As of season 4, Hera appears to have made General:

> **Hera:** Phoenix Two, you've got the wingman.
>
> **Mart:** Already on it, General.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars: Rebels* Season 4 Episode 9: "Rebel Assault"</sup>

And this is the rank she holds in *Rogue One*, [according to](http://ew.com/movies/rogue-one-rebels-references/rogue-one-and-rebels-6/) Dave Filoni<sup>1</sup>:

> "I can clarify that's absolutely Hera being paged, not her dad," Filoni says. "The movie gives that away, but I would rather have all the [references] be right. Hera will eventually become a general in the Rebel Alliance."

### Kanan - Unknown, possibly Commander

There's a scene early in "The Holocrons of Fate" where a Rebel pilot addresses a Commander, with no name given:

> **Rebel Pilot:** Coming up on the rendezvous point, Commander, but the transport's not responding. It looks like it was attacked.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 3 Episode 2: "The Holocrons of Fate"</sup>

Since the only other people in the room are Kanan, Ezra, and another pilot, odds are good that he's referring to one of the Jedi. There's another moment in "The Last Battle" where Rex addresses Kanan as "Commander" before correcting himself:

> **Kanan:** We should move.
>
> **Rex:** Right Commander. Uh, Kanan.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 3 Episode 5: "The Last Battle"</sup>

Upon first watching the episode, I assumed this was part of Rex flashing back to the Clone Wars; however, it does seem unusual for him to address Kanan as a "Commander" rather than a "General" if that were the case.

### Sabine - unknown

Sabine has yet to be associated with a rank on the show. About all we can say is that she's subordinate to Commander Sato, which doesn't tell us a whole lot.

### Zeb - Captain

The season 3 episode "Warhead" has Zeb frequently referred to as a Captain, by himself and others; a handful of examples:

> **Sabine:** Carry on, Captain Orrelios.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **EXD-9:** *[scanning Zeb]* Species, Lasat. Designation, military. Rank, unknown.
>
> **Zeb:** Captain Orrelios, at your service.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Rebel Officer** *[over PA system]* Captain Orrelios to the command center for a priority message.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **AP-5:** Well, whatever the outcome, you performed admirably, Captain.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 3 Episode 13: "Warhead"</sup>

### Rex - Captain

Although this is also the rank Rex held in the Clone Wars, he's still occasionally referred to by this title; for example:

> **Hera:** Sabine; I have a mission for you and Chop. Thanks to Captain Rex, I found an old base where we might be able to salvage some much-needed medical supplies.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars Rebels* Season 2 Episode 3: "Always Two There Are"</sup>

### Chopper and AP-5 - unknown; likely none

Droids aren't really considered people in the strictest sense, and there's no indication that they're ordinarily conferred a rank in the Rebellion, or in the Republic military on which the Rebellion is based.

There's an interesting quirk to that, which Donatello Swansino points out in comments, in [K-3PO](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/K-3PO), the white 3PO unit seen on Hoth in *Empire Strikes Back*; K-3PO is seen with two red dots on its plating, consistent with the insignia for a rebel captain. However, I would suggest this is a special case, and not something we can apply to Chopper and AP-5, for a few reasons:

- Although Legends materials established K-3PO as having been granted the rank of Captain (likely to explain the markings), this has not been addressed in any Canon works
- Even in Legends, K-3PO being "[recognized](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/K-3PO/Legends#Recognition)" was a long and difficult process, and one specifically mentioned as being unusual; K-3PO is the exception, rather than the rule
- Neither Chopper nor AP-5 have any exterior markings that could be mistaken for rank insignia

In all likelihood, the droids have no rank at all.

---

<sup>1</sup> Hat tip to DBPriGuy for the source

Comment: Evidence that General Syndulla is indeed Hera: http://ew.com/movies/rogue-one-rebels-references/rogue-one-and-rebels-6

Comment: @DBPriGuy Well hush my mouth. And I was really rooting for Peggy Syndulla, too

Comment: Droids have had ranks within the Rebel Alliance. K-3PO is the prime example of this.

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino I'm not familiar with that canon tidbit; what rank does K-3PO hold, and when is it referenced?

Comment: K-3PO was in Echo Base during The Empire Strikes Back. It appears to be a captain.

Comment: All Jedi are Generals or Commanders in the GAR.

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino Oh, you're talking about the two red dots on his (her?) shoulder? Possibly so, but I still stand by my answer here; there's no indication that giving ranks to droids is normal, and none of the *Rebels* droids have similar markings

Comment: @Valorum True, but this isn't the GAR; I'm not convinced the rebellion is following the same policy

Comment: @JasonBaker - Indeed. I was just commenting

Comment: @RogueJedi He was suspended; I'm not sure if that's the same thing. I'll have to re-watch the episode

Answer (score -3):

I imagine that in Imperial records they might have ranks such as "rebel scum third grade", "rebel scum second grade", and "rebel scum first grade".

Hera may be a captain in rank or might only be the captain or commander of the ship the *Ghost*.  The others might have the position of "crew member" for all we known.

If the *Ghost* gang have not formally enrolled in the service of a political or military institution and are not paid and supplied by that institution they might not have any ranks.   They might all be civilians.

Comment: The Rebel Alliance is a voluntary militia. Doesn't stop them from assigning ranks to the recruits